# Как нужно отправить форму чтобы удалить новость

Tags: php, html, mvc

Как удалить новость, что нужно в форме дописать чтобы удалить ту категорию где нажал кнопку **УДАЛИТЬ**

```
<table class="table table-hover ">
<thead >
<tr>
<th class="text-center" >  ID </th>
<th class="text-center"> Категорія </th>
<th class="text-center"> Змінити </th>
<th class="text-center"> Видалити </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($data['menu'] as $category) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $category['id'] ?></td>
        <td>
            <a class="" href="Admin/category/<?php echo $category['id'] ?>" role="button">
                <?php echo $category['category'] ?>
            </a>
        </td>
        <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post">
        <td><a class="btn btn-warning"  type="submit" ">Обновить</a></td>
        </form>
        <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post">
        <td><a class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" ">Удалить</a></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Категорія
                
            
        
    Submit

[image: **введите сюда описание изображения**]

Например, у меня в форме есть два submit один на обновление другой на удаление, как мне опредилить какой именно из них я нажал?

Comment: Удалите значения из БД

Comment: как удалить из БД я знаю "DELETE FROM `table`" WHERE `id`=1, но как мне взнать когда я нажимаю на кнопку какую именно я нажал?Какую именно я хочю удалить категорию?

Comment: `type="submit"` у тэга `а`? И что оно делает?

Comment: Надо на кнопку submit нажать, остальное должен php код делать.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<td>
  <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $category['id'] ?>" />
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Удалить</button>
  </form>
</td>
```